# Can load dll in VBA, how to do it in Python?

Tags: python, vba, excel

I'm a amateur programmer and I program to support some cleantech science that I work on as a part of my day job. I am a total newb so I apologize in advance if my question is vague / not clear.

I am trying to load a dll that I can successfully load in VBA but I'm having a hard time doing it in python. Here's the module in VBA:

```vb
Public Declare Function Gwrite Lib "C:\Program Files\LQElectronics\UGSimple\UGSimpleAPI\LQUGSimple_s.dll" Alias "#100" (ByVal address As Integer, ByVal SCPI As String) As Integer
Public Declare Function Gread Lib "C:\Program Files\LQElectronics\UGSimple\UGSimpleAPI\LQUGSimple_s.dll" Alias "#101" (ByVal address As Long) As String
```

The code in the excel sheet looks something like this

```vb
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim proc As Integer
    Dim result As String
    proc = Gwrite(7, "*IDN?")
    result = Gread(7)
    MsgBox (result)
End Sub
```

The above code blocks work really well, but I want to translate this into python. Can you please help me? Thank you so much for reading my questions and I'm available to answer any clarifications.

Comment: Solution: testlib = ctypes.CDLL("C:\Program Files (x86)\LQElectronics\UGSimple\UGSimpleAPI\LQUGSimple_c.dll") testlib.Gwrite.restype = ctypes.c_int
testlib.Gread.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

Answer (score 0):

@Toby, you supplied the answer to your own Q -- but in a comment so it's unreadable!  Here's a readable form:

```
testlib = ctypes.CDLL('C:\Program Files(x86)\LQElectronics\UGSimple\UGSimpleAPI\LQUGSimple_c.dll')
testlib.Gwrite.restype = ctypes.c_int
testlib.Gread.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
```